# Jms with abstract class as a MessageListener using spring?

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic, abstract-class

I need your help to confirm my design is ok. **Is it a mistake to make an abstract-class implements MessageListener because i can't find any resources doing that.**

This solution is working only when i set the message listener programatically otherwise spring complain that the class is abstract if i try to do spring configuration only.

What i want to do is to provide an API for consuming a specific queue which each application has to consume and implements her own OnMessage method.

The API basically:

- connect to JMS
- consume one message
- transform json to object in the abstract class, with the non abstract method
- call abstract method

Applications have to implement the abstract method and then do what they want with object.

**My solution :**

```
public abstract class MyReceiver implements MessageListener {
    public void startReceiving() throws JMSException {
        context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("jms-context-client.xml");
        AbstractMessageListenerContainer container = context.getBean("jmsContainer", AbstractMessageListenerContainer.class);
        container.setMessageSelector("JMSCorrelationID = '" + this.clientID + "'");
        container.setMessageListener(this); // <-- good practice ?
        container.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        // transform json data to object
        // call abstract method that the client MUST implement
        onMessageAbstract(response);
    }

    public abstract void onMessageAbstract(MyObject response);
}
```

**the spring configuration :**

```
<bean id="pooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" init-method="start"
    destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="maxConnections" value="20" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.spring.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL"><value><![CDATA[failover:(tcp://127.0.0.1:61616)?randomize=false&initialReconnectDelay=1000&useExponentialBackOff=false]]></value</property>
</bean>
<bean id="queueCommonMessage" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="foo.bar" />
</bean>
<bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer" scope="prototype">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="destination" ref="queueCommonMessage" />
    <property name="autoStartup" value="false" />
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="false"/>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" />
</bean>
```

**example of application using the API**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {
        MyReceiver receiver = new MyReceiver("clientID") {
            @Override
            public void onMessageAbstract(MyObject response) {
                logger.debug("OK");
            }
        };
        receiver.startReceiving();    
    }
```

Thanks !

Comment: Can you provide more info on this container object? Details about your your connection, number of sessions and the queue you are connecting to?

Comment: ive edit the question, to begin the application have to consume one message at a time no concurrent consumer BUT they will be many application using the same api and consuming on the same queue for their specific clientID (see setMessageSelector)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as there is only one consumer or to be more precise as long as there is only one sessions that is creating your consumer(which has your messagelistener attached) there will be no issues.

To put it in one line as long as your MyReceiver class is stateless there is no problem and will work fine for different applications consuming from same queue.

Problem will arise when your MyReceiver class has some state. For example lets say you have a count variable in it which increments every time you receive a message to track total number of messages received. Now if you say

```
container.setMessageListener(this);
```

for two receivers created from same session of a single connection then they will share the instance of your MyReceiver class leading to race condition.

Generally what I have seen in JMS codes is

```
container.setMessageListener(new customMessageListener());
```

or even an inner anonymous class.

But for your requirement your design looks good. No need to create extra Objects.

Just for the record though of two or more receivers receive from a single queue at the same time a message may go to any receiver.

Also I don't get when you say **consume one message**.

If you are using asynchronous receiving. You cannot guarantee only one message will be received until you close your connection. If your application want to receive only one message at a time use `receiver.receive()`(synchronous/blocking receive).